# D3js: How to load a tsv file and select only the data which is available for two different points

Tags: d3.js

Hello guys I started doing some D3js and I am able to make some visualizations 
with data that I place in an array like:

```
var data = [20, 50, 70, 90];
```

now I'd like to load data from a TSV file that is available at two different points for example the income of a person in 1990 and 2000, 
so I would have a TSV file like this

```
income_of_person    1990    1995    2000  
person1             30000   32000   35000 
person2             .       32000   35000  
person3             30000   32000   35000
```

now I'd like to only use the data of person1 and person3 as they have their income information available for both 1990 and 2000

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not filter the data before using it in d3 ? If you use [d3.tsv()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#tsv) I guess that you can do something like:

```
var data = data.filter(function(d){
   return (typeof d['1990']!=='undefined')&&(typeof d['2000']!=='undefined')
})
```